# NHibernate Left Join - in the join condition

Tags: nhibernate

```
<property name="MId" column="M_Id" update="false" insert="false" />

<many-to-one name="MGH" class="MGH" lazy="false">
  <column name="M_Id" />
</many-to-one>

<join table="SXX2">
  <key column="Study_Key" />
  <property name="GG" column="GG"/>
</join>
```

I want to join the SXX2 table with left join

Answer (score 2):

You're after the 'optional' attribute, ie:

```
<join table="SXX2" optional="true">
  <key column="Study_Key" />
  <property name="GG" column="GG"/>
</join>
```